# DNS server bind9 + apache2 on Ubuntu Server VM + localhost problems connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, dns, apache-http-server

I'm trying to resolve some problems with my DNS server + Apache2 and local machine.

I've got Ubuntu server on VirtualBox with NAT network adapter.

I tried to create DNS server for my page `praktykant.local` On Ubuntu server VM can only access the page by `10.0.2.15` (Ubuntu server IP) or by `dns1.praktykant.local` In my local machine I can access only page by `127.0.0.1` with port forwarding.

Port forwarding I tried: [image: port forwarding]

`bind9`: [image: praktykant.local]

[image: named.conf.options file]

[image: named.conf.local]

Apache2 files: [image: praktykant.local.conf]

Questions I've got are two.

1. What is wrong in configuration files that Ubuntu server works only with `dns1.praktykant.local` instead of `praktynat.local`?
2. How to configure my port forwarding and local machine (Windows) to use DNS server and resolve `dns1.praktykant.local` or `praktykant.local` to Apache server startup page?

Is it better to setup bridged network adapter?

Comment: Whenever I switch network adapter to bridged and change IPs in praktykant.local, the webpage does not start either from praktykant.local oraz dns1.praktykant.local. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Ok i've managed to enable connecting by DNS to dns1.praktykant.local in Bridged network adapter. I forgot about resolv.conf file :D Anyway still got a problem with FQDN. Would love to have a page named praktykant.local not dns1.praktykant.local